# Is it possible to abuse allocate_ids? Can I risk running out of ids?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Questions up front:

From what I understand, allocate_ids will reserve a block of ids, that will not be used by the datastore either for new entity creation, or another allocate_ids call.  Is that correct?

If so are unused allocated ids ever reused?  If so, what's the timeout period?

If unused allocated ids are never reused, can I risk running out of ids?  Is there any other detrimental effects (ie ids getting overly huge).

Background:

I'm trying to create a system to prevent creating duplicate objects via a REST API.
I'm calling allocate_ids when I create the initial form, and embed the id in the form.
When the form is submitted to the REST API, it creates the object with the embedded id.  If the same form is submitted twice, I'll know not to create the duplicate object.

It's possible that the form will be viewed many times without being submitted, in which case I run the risk of using up a lot of ids where I never create entities.  Is there any problem with this plan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues:

1. Do not expose datastore IDs to client side. As noted by @Shay, this is a security risk, as users could directly manipulate data.
2. The problem of duplicate form submission is basically a problem of application workflow. To solve this I prefer client-side solutions (javascript) but if you insist on server-side solution, then use [sessions](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Enabling_Sessions). Create a bogus ID, save it in session and also set it as hidden field in form. When form is submitted check for this field.

Comment: This answered my question, but I'm still curious if ids returned from allocate_ids() are lost forever if unused.

Comment: Yes, they __should__ be lost forever. Otherwise this function would make no sense.

Comment: What? No, exposing datastore IDs to a user is not a security risk, and does not allow them to manipulate data. Letting them _set_ the ID without further checks is a risk.

Comment: Ok, in his case it is a security risk because as far as explained he does save data by just checking if ID is present. But, thanks for the comment - it's always good to be precise in this matters. Good to see you back in action on SO.

Comment: FWIW I ended up using a UUID stored in a session.  I didn't really think it was a security risk because I used the datastore ID to verify that it wasn't an already existing entity.  The main problem I had was I had to verify the ID against already allocated IDs.  This was a pain.

Answer (score 1):

Your system can be easily hacked, someone can change the value of the ID manually and it will override an existing entity.
When creating a new object just post the data and let AppEngine generate and id for you.

allocate_id works in the 64 bit space (at least) so even if you generate 10 ids per seconds it will take thousands of years to run out of them.

Comment: Nope, if I just let the form post, then the same for posted twice will generate two entities, with different ids, which is exactly what I'm trying to prevent.

Comment: Then don't use ids, use random number that the user can change to override someone else entity.